# Webpack/Crypto-Browserify Reference Error: assignment to undeclared variable _crypto

Tags: webpack, twilio, browserify

Totally stumped. I have a React App that imports a helper file. That helper file contains ONLY the following right now (and the file is loading correctly):

```
var accountSid = '<secret_id>'; 
var authToken  = '<secret_token>';
var client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);
```

I get the this error: "Reference Error: assignment to undeclared variable _crypto"

The source map takes me to this block of code in 'bundle.js,' compiled by Webpack:

```
/* 262 */
/***/ function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

    /* WEBPACK VAR INJECTION */(function(global, Buffer) {'use strict';

    (function () {
      var g = ('undefined' === typeof window ? global : window) || {};
      _crypto = g.crypto || g.msCrypto || __webpack_require__(263);
      module.exports = function (size) {
        // Modern Browsers
        if (_crypto.getRandomValues) {
          var bytes = new Buffer(size); //in browserify, this is an extended Uint8Array
          /* This will not work in older browsers.
           * See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.crypto.getRandomValues
           */

          _crypto.getRandomValues(bytes);
          return bytes;
        } else if (_crypto.randomBytes) {
          return _crypto.randomBytes(size);
        } else throw new Error('secure random number generation not supported by this browser\n' + 'use chrome, FireFox or Internet Explorer 11');
      };
    })();
    /* WEBPACK VAR INJECTION */}.call(exports, (function() { return this; }()), __webpack_require__(257).Buffer))

/***/ },
```

The function comes from a file called 'rng.js' inside '(webpack) > ~/node-libs-browser/~ > crypto-browserify' 
When I comment out the twilio instantiation method, the error goes away. It didn't show up until I started using the twilio module.

Anyone seen this before or have a suggestion as to how I can fix it? Thnx.

Comment: Most likely, [`twilio`](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node) cannot be used in a browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It looks like you're trying to use the [Twilio Node module](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/node) in the browser. This is not supported and very much not recommended either. For one reason:

If you list your account credentials in your front end then they are available for any malicious user to steal and use against your Twilio account spending all your money on whoever they want to call or SMS.

We recommend that you make your API calls to Twilio on a server and send the requests by Ajax if you need to make a dynamic front end.

Comment: Would love to see Twilio or someone put out a tutorial on how to develop React apps with a third-party API. There's plenty of resources for running a React App with webpack. But not as many for getting it to run on a real development environment where you can make server calls. Recommendations welcome!!

Comment: There have been a couple of blog posts on this, notably this one, which might help: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/11/reactjs-tutorial-call-monitoring-with-react-express-and-socket-io.html. We will probably write more on it too, so keep an eye on the blog!